# Lasso Line Selection

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, geometry

I am building a 2D graphing application using Qt. The graph has nodes and edges which the user can create and selection is done via a lasso selection tool. So far I have been able to implement node selection using a simple [Point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm. However, now I need to implement edge selection.

Currently I have three classes representing this graph: Node, Edge and Graph. Node is a simple X, Y container. Edge has a pointer to the source and target node. And graph contains a list of nodes and edges.

I know how I can select edges when nodes are part of the selection however how can I implement edge selection when the corresponding nodes are not part of the selection (i.e. Edge-Polygon intersection test). I say polygon since my lasso tool constructs a list of points representing an n-sided polygon.

Here is an example of the algorithm I need (Color red represents the expected result).

[image]

> *This is not for school but rather a hobby project I am working on.*

Comment: How do you represent the selection? Did you convert it to a polygon (as suggested by your mention of the point in polygon algorithm)?

Comment: yes, the selection is represented by a polygon.

Comment: @Dave Do you use `QGraphicsView` framework to display this ? Because I've done exactly the same thing with `QGraphicsView` framework, and there is no need for any algorithm, a simple high-level call is enough.

Comment: @totem I am however I am using my own paint method. I also figured out a solution on my own, will post it when I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$selected = [];

for each $polygon in $scene:
    if $polygon.intersects($selectionPolygon):
        for each $edge in $polygon:
            for each $selectionEdge in $selectionPolygon:
                if $edge.crosses($selectionEdge):
                    $selected.push($edge)
                    break
                endif
            end
        end
    endif
end
```